# How to format and indent CSS in Notepad++?

Tags: css, plugins, formatting, notepad++, indentation

I have `CSS` file generated by `Sass` compiler, but the text inside the `CSS` file is all on one line.

Is there a way to indent and or format it properly on `Notepad++` and `VSCode`?

[image]

I have tried installing the `XML Tools` plugin, and then pressing the `Pretty print`, but nothing happens.

Comment: You can use an online tool like [this](https://unminify.com/), there's plenty of them out there :)

Comment: @VilleKoo How does this work? I pasted the code inside, but nothing happens. I downloaded it, but it's just a txt file, and the code inside looks the same.

Comment: I'm afraid there are no N++ plugins  that do such job. You can replace all `;--` with `;\r\n--`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To format CSS in Notepad++:

- Go to **Plugins > Plugin Manager > Show Plugin Manager**.
- Select the **JSTool** Plugin and click <kbd>Install</kbd>
- Go to Plugins > JSTool > JSFormat **OR** use keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>

[image]

is resulting in:

[image]

Comment: Not exactly what we want, needs further replacement `^    ([a-zA-Z]+) - ([a-zA-Z]+)\s*:` with ````    \1-\2:````. Maybe not just that.